# Where can I find the ownership of a specific aircraft registered in the UAE?

Tags: aircraft-registration, uae

Is there a website where I can find the ownership of a specific aircraft - or in my case a specific corporate jet - registered in the UAE? I am conducting some research on corporate jets and need some detailed information about the ownership of a particular aircraft.

Comment: mabye the plane spotters have "caught" it: https://www.planespotters.net/

Comment: i checked planespotters.net and few other sources and got all the information about the aircraft itself including its MSN, production site, engine type and registration number but no information on its ownership. It is a A319 corporate jet registered in UAE, which makes it a bit more difficult to find out about the ownership due to strict UAE laws. Was hoping someone more knowledgeable than me might be able to help.

Comment: Try this site as well <http://www.landings.com> and select Databases